# Angular app url shows a '#', is there a way to delete it?

Tags: angular

My angular application url shows a `#`
I don't want to display the `#` and I do not know how to delete it.

This is the url of dashboard page - `http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard`

I want to find a way to make it like - `this http://localhost:4200/dashboard`

**app.routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    }, {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [{
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.module#AdminLayoutModule'
        }]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            useHash: true
        })
    ],
```

**admin.routing.module**

```
export const AdminLayoutRoutes: Routes =[
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'connecter', component: ConnecterComponent },
    { path: 'inscrire', component: InscrireComponent },
    { path: 'bibliography', component: BibliographyComponent },
    { path: 'user-profile', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: UserProfileComponent },
    { path: 'produits', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: ProduitViewComponent },
    { path: 'produits/view/:id', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: SingleProduitComponent },
    { path: 'commandes', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: CommandesViewComponent },
    { path: 'commandes/view/:id', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: SingleCommandeComponent },
    { path: 'produits/new', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: ProduitFormComponent },
    { path: 'typography', component: TypographyComponent },
    { path: 'icons', component: IconsComponent },
    { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  CommonModule,
  RouterModule.forChild(AdminLayoutRoutes),
]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your router module you have the following

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: true
})
```

remove `useHash: true` so it should now look like this

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```